# Как повлияет большое количество поддоменов на задержки при открытии сайтов?

Tags: веб-программирование, домен, поддомены

К примеру, есть домен: mydomen.ru и, условно, 500 подддоменов: n1.mydomen.ru, n2.mydomen.ru и т.д. Увеличит ли это задержки при открытии сайтов, которые размещены на поддоменах и основном домене? Если да, то из-за чего?

Comment: Количество поддоменов на задержку открытия НЕ влияет. А вот уровень - влияет, но не значительно: клиенту приходится делать несколько DNS запросов, для ru.wikipedia.org - 4 зеленые стрелочки (на практике - 2 запроса) https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/DNS-names-ru.svg/400px-DNS-names-ru.svg.png . Вот что действительно может тормозить: перегруженный хостинг, CMS и ваш домашний провайдер

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!